# How to create table as generic component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, generics, typescript, angular2-template

I have this table below. This kind of table can be found anywhere in my project, with different number of columns, with-or-without header column. That's why I would like to create a generic component, more simple, and have his own CSS.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px"></th>
      <th> {{ 'nameColumn_result_name' | translate }} </th>
      <th> {{ 'nameColumn_result_date' | translate }} 
    </tr>
  </thead>                  
  <tbody #lines>
    <tr #lineSelected *ngFor="let result of results" 
      (click)="appendLine($event, lineSelected, result)" 
      (contextmenu)="multipleSelection($event)">
      <td (click)="selectUnitaryLine($event, result)" class="arrowDown"></td>
      <td>{{result.name}}</td>
      <td>{{result.date}}</td>
    </tr>       
    <tr *ngIf="result && result .length == 0" >
      <td colspan="10" class="text-center">{{ 'no_result _found' | translate }}</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like something like this :

```
<CustomTable [data]="results" (click)="appendLine($event, lineSelected, result)" (contextmenu)="multipleSelection($event)">
   <CustomTableColumn style="width: 100px" (click)="selectUnitaryLine($event, result)"></CustomTableColumn>
   <CustomTableColumn [data]="name"> {{ 'nameColumn_result_name' | translate }} </CustomTableColumn>
   <CustomTableColumn [data]="date"> {{ 'nameColumn_result_date' | translate }}</CustomTableColumn> 
</CustomTable>
```

The idea is that CustomTable generate `table`, `thead`, `tbody` and `tr` and `CustomTableColumn` generate `td`. The `events (click)` are not generic. It can be add by the page which use this table.

So I create my component:

**customtable.component.ts**

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'CustomTable',
   templateUrl: './customtable.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./customtable.component.css']
 })
 (...)
```

I don't know how to do that?

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: hey just wondering if you could solve adding nested components like this?